# extension installing after not showing admin panel

Tags: admin, error

Extension installing ..it's ok...
But not showing admin panel( ↓ img and my error log)

[image]

> 2016-01-12T05:50:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():
>   Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the
>   document  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line
>   29213
>
> 2016-01-12T05:50:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():
>   <reference name="left">  in
>   /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
>
> 2016-01-12T05:50:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^
>   in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213

Answer (score 1):

Follow bellow steps:

**Step : 1** Open file includes\config.php on magento root folder

**Code replace from** :

```
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

**TO:**

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

**Step : 2** Enable this trough Admin

First disable cache. Go to Magento back-end - `System -> Tools -> Compilation` Enable. After you Enable this functionality run Run Compilation mode.

[More Details](http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=49)